# A static page vs a category page. Which is better in terms of SEO and ranking possibilities?

Tags: seo, page, post, architecture

From an SEO perspective, consider the following website presenting mobile phones. The website will have a section for "Best phones" where you can find a list of phones with short descriptions and a link to a full description for the phone you wish to read about.

Is it better to use 1. or 2.?

1. Using posts for phone descriptions and review, and put these posts in a certain category. That category will stand as the "best phones" list.

   > ```
   > example.com/best-phones/  <-- this is a category
   > example.com/best-phones/samsung-galaxy/ <-- this is a post
   > ```
2. Creating normal static pages for both the "best phones list" as well as for the phones themselves.

   > ```
   > example.com/best-phones/ <-- this is a static page containing a list of phones and a short description for each one
   > example.com/best-phones/samsung-galaxy/  <-- this is a static page too containing a full description of Samsung Galaxy
   > ```

The content and linking would be the same. I guess the main difference is [page vs post] and [category vs page]. I know that posts are time sensitive. So that is why I am not sure I should use posts instead of pages.

I am strictly asking in regards to SEO. For example I know the first option would be much easier to update and maintain but I am not asking about that.

Strictly regarding SEO and how these websites would rank in a search engines?

Comment: The way you want to generate your pages (static or dynamic) has no repercussion for SEO.

Comment: @ClawDuda Can you clarify this a bit so others will be able to understand it easier (e.g., with URL examples).

Comment: Imagine a website about phones. One section of the website would be called "best phones". There, you will find a list with a lot of phones and each will have a link to that specific phone's page where you can read about it.
So , my question is : What is better for SEO and ranking ?

1. The "best-phones" to be a category and each particular phone to have a post in that category 
2. The best phones to be a page and each phone to have a page as well 
The difference is that the phone descriptions would be on pages vs posts and the list of "best phones" would be a page vs category.

Comment: i updated the question . I hope it is ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference for SEO because URLs, linking and content would be the same.

Even if you want an answer regarding SEO, your choice must be driven by which site architecture is the most relevant in your case. A good site architecture improves users browsing on your site and don't forget taking care of users is the best option to improve SEO.

Do you want a site or a blog? I think if you want a blog, choosing the categories and posts is most probably the best option but if you want a site, choosing pages system is most probably the best option. Therefore, regarding your situation, I would use the pages system.

Comment: But if i decide for the "post and category" method, won't posts have a shorter life in search engine indexation ? I know that they are time sensitive. Perhaps this is another question entirely. What are your thoughts on this ?

Comment: Posts and categories are used for a blog, not a site. If you want a site, use pages. That way, you're sure to do the right choice (especially if you use a CMS).

Comment: but how do you categorize a site and a blog ? For example a newspaper can use WordPress and have news in posts. But you cannot call it a blog, right? Please don't misunderstand me. Judging by your reputation here i am sure you are right. It's just that i don't understand how you differentiate a site from a blog, in this case.

Comment: OK sites and blogs can have the same architecture but not in all cases. If you want comments system, time sorted pages (the most recent to the top), choose a blog system. I think in your case, you should use pages because presenting phones has no needs to comments and to be time sorted.

Comment: in case i want these pages to be a review for each phone , and users to be able to comment or post their thoughts do you recommend using posts or use pages and find another way to allow comments and such just to avoid "time sensitive" posts ?

Comment: In general, you can't use comments without "time sensitive" posts. That way, I would find another way to allow comments in the phones pages.